# how can i convert date to solar date?in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a huge number of dates in my database, and that is saved in a format like this `12/18/2013`

Now I have to change it to solar date like this `1392/09/27`.

Is there anything to convert it?(get Lunar date and change it to solar date)

I need it in vb.net

Comment: Have you thought about maybe writing a function to convert it?

Comment: If you want vb then why is this tagged c#?

Comment: in the first I'm searching about ready classes or libraries.i don't know if there is something like this or not.If there is something in c# i can change it to vb ;)

Comment: @gleng, should I have guilt that i did it for him, or feel pride that I solved a problem? ;)

Comment: Which culture are you talking about?  Can you [pick it from this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx)?

Comment: Oh my... [Tony the Pony is at it again](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[System.Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace in .NET hosts a [number of different calendars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can convert between these by creating a date in one, then getting the day, month and year out of the other calendars.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim gregorianDate = DateTime.Parse("12/18/2013")

    Dim solarCalendar = New PersianCalendar()

    Dim solarDay = solarCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(gregorianDate)
    Dim solarMonth = solarCalendar.GetMonth(gregorianDate)
    Dim solarYear = solarCalendar.GetYear(gregorianDate)

    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", solarYear, solarMonth, solarDay)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Output:

> 1392/9/27

After a bit of figuring, the [PersianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the "Solar" date that you are looking for.

Comment: is there any function to convert dates?

Comment: @user3091887 something like that function would work for you.  I am not getting your exact output however, so I wonder if the Hijri calendar is the right one.  But perhaps your values are off?

Comment: thank you so much,actually i need something like this,but there is a problem this is Hijri date and i need Solar date.is there any class for Solar calender?

Comment: @user3091887 Can you give me an example of what you mean by solar calendar?

Comment: @user3091887 for example a web page that shows this type of calendar?

Comment: There is a property on the hijri calendar called [HijriAdjustment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar.hijriadjustment(v=vs.95).aspx).  The culture, as noted by @StevenDoggart and others also needs to be determined.

Comment: no HijriAdjustment is not Solar calender,now is 1392 but in hijri is 1435,Solar calender is "fa" culture

Comment: @user3091887 you need the PersianCalendar.  I've adjusted my code.

Comment: @user3091887 let me know if you need anything else. be sure to check the checkmark if this is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the culture that you want to use when you are parsing date/times, like this:

```
Dim parsedDateTime As Date = Date.Parse("12/18/2013", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

You can also specify culture that you want to use when you are formatting the date/time as a string, like this:

```
Dim formatted As String = parsedDateTime.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("th"))
```

So, you can convert from one culture to another by combining those two steps, like this:

```
Public Function ConvertDateStringToCulture(dateString As String, fromCulture As String, toCulture As String) As String
    Dim parsedDateTime As Date = Date.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(fromCulture))
    Dim formatted As String = parsedDateTime.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(toCulture))
    Return formatted
End Function
```

Then, for example, if you want to convert from a US date to a Thailand date, you could do it like this:

```
Dim converted As String = ConvertDateStringToCulture("12/18/2013", "en-US", "th")
```

However, you need to pick the right culture to go from and to.  [Here is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) of the supported cultures.

Comment: thank you ,i need "fa" culture ,and i tried it but i don't know why the result is not correct!!!